# Vimeo thumbnails with black bars

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

we're fetching vimeo videos via the vimeo php SDK and render them on our website.
For the thumbnail we're currently iterating vimeo's response items and checking the "pictures" key. By default we use the last entry, which should be the one with the highest resolution. This worked fine in most cases, until we tried vertical (portrait) videos.

This is the test video I'm trying to embed: https://player.vimeo.com/video/736101184
For this video I'm getting this link as the last entry within the pictures array: https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/1481190475-3f2281eaa6f59bca29010b27d119c416986fd7d2670ad5852814089c52734d74-d_1920x1080?r=pad
As you can see it has black bars around it. I can remove the `?r=pad` from the URL to get it without them, but then the thumbnail is cut off, as in it's not the full thumbnail.

So my question is: how do I determine which picture to use as the thumbnail, so that it matches the video resolution and preferrably has no black bars around it?

Comment: Why don't you do an extra call for the thumbnail without r=rpad?

Comment: @MarkusZeller because without the `?r=pad` parameter in the URL, the thumbnail doesn't look right either. It's cut off without the parameter.

Comment: When you know the video proportion, then you can cut out 720x1280 from the center.

Comment: Yeah but afaik the API does not return this information about the video resolution

Comment: Why don't you put your desired resolution in the URL? 
https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/1481190475-3f2281eaa6f59bca29010b27d119c416986fd7d2670ad5852814089c52734d74-d_720x1280?r=pad

Comment: Aah I see. Okay now I just have to find out, how I can do this automatically. Basically I need the API to give me the proper resolution, so that I can get the correct size of the thumbnail. Thank you!